# Explanation of proof involving Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Consider the condition:

$|f(x)-f(y)|)=\mathcal O(|x-y|^\alpha)$ at $x\to y\ $ for $\alpha >0$

Now, for some functions $f$ we can't find $\alpha>1$ so that this is true.

The author says the following:

For most cases we can eliminate this limitation by shifting the function by a linear function:

For functions that are differentiable at $y$, from Taylor's theorem with Peano's form of remainder, we know that

$$f(x)=f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)+o(x-y)$$

> We can therefore study $g(x):=f(x)-f'(y)(x-y)$ instead of $f(x)$. We will then have $g(x)-g(y)=o(x-y)$ which has an $\alpha$ value at least as large as $f$.

Furthermore  if $f$ has well defined second derivative, we then have

$$f(x)=f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)+\frac{f''(\xi_L)}{2}(x-y)^2$$, that is $$g(x)-g(y)=\frac{f''(\xi_L)}{2}(x-y)^2$$ which implies $\alpha =2$

If $f''(y)=0$, we can apply similar arguments to higher order derivatives to find the best $\alpha$.

**So, my question is**

> Why can we study $g$ instead of $f$? And what does he mean by shifting the function by a linear function?

Comment: this expression $g(x):=f(x)-f'(y)(x-y)$ is the shifting of $f$ by a linear function (in the sense of calculus) $h(x):=f'(y)(x-y)$

Comment: What's the context of these arguments? I am lost…